# Immersive full-screen mode lost after soft keyboard use

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

My application has a perfectly functional immersive full-screen mode based off of onWindowFocusChanged.

When the soft keyboard is opened (at least from an EditText), the bar at the top with the string from android:label in the AndroidManifest.xml comes down at the same time the keyboard comes up. Additionally, when the keyboard is closed, both the bar and the navigation buttons persist until some other action that uses them is performed.

Obviously, the soft keyboard does not trigger the onWindowFocusChanged. Is there some other trigger that can be used with the keyboard? Frequent solutions from the web involve listening for a resize of the main layouts, but the keyboard and top bar act as an overlay when the EditText is not below where the keyboard covers....

This is incredibly aggravating, as I have never used an app that has this problem. Am I missing something obvious? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.